# Is tileJSON supported by ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Does ArcGIS 10.2 for Server support tileJSON? I mean, can I retrieve in some way the tileJSON from and ArcgisTiledLayer ?

I need this so as to use it with wax library and have a grid along with the tiled image which will contain the encoded location of the features that the image shows.